# making table from fasta sequences, python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have around 500 protein sequences in fasta format, I got from a blastp search. From those sequences, I need to have the protein name, organism, Uniprot ID and if possible the protein family, so that I can build a table with that information.

Is there any way I can do it using python? some function that comunicate with Uniprot? how can I parse the information from the fasta header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) that has a FASTA parser. After parsing you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) `DataFrame` to build a table. Without a snippet of example data it is difficult to provide a more  thourogh answer, but it should be doable with about 5 lines of code :)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open("example.fasta", "rU") as handle:
    print list(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))
```